# What is the scale and does it depend on the print out size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, scale

I am new to ArcGIS and I would like to know what is the scale in ArcGIS and does it depend on the print out size or display?

Can any one explain all about topic scale in the ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Explaining "all about topic scale in ArcGIS" is too broad a question for the Q&A format of this site, but there is a **[HowTo:  Print an ArcMap layout to an exact scale - 9.x](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/36264)** that explains how to obtain exact scales on hardcopy maps.  I suspect that this may be the information that you seek.